# How to set HTTP_PROXY using Selenium RemoteWebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-remotedriver

Here is my current code to launch browser without any proxy:

```
                properties = getGridProperties();
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = null;
                FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
                    profile.setPreference("layout.css.devPixelsPerPx","0.9");
                    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions().setProfile(profile);
                    options.addPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false);
                    if (properties.containsKey("hub.gecko.driver.path"))
                        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", properties.getProperty("hub.gecko.driver.path"));
                    capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                    capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
                    if (browserType.equalsIgnoreCase("oldfirefox")) {
                        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);
                        capabilities.setCapability("platform", "LINUX");
                        options.merge(capabilities);
                    }
                printInfo("initRemoteWebDriver:started:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                capabilities.setCapability("idleTimeout", 150);
                String nodeURL = "http://" + properties.getProperty("grid.hub.host") + "/wd/hub";
                capabilities.setCapability("idleTimeout", 150);
                capabilities.setCapability("name", this.getClass().getCanonicalName());

                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), capabilities);
                setDriver(driver);
                getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
                printInfo("****Firefox browser launched***");
                printInfo("initRemoteWebDriver:finished:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Desired proxy details to be set:

```
HTTP_PROXY = 'http://www-proxy.us.abc.com:80'
HTTPS_PROXY = 'http://www-proxy.us.abc.com:80'
```

What is the simplest way to do this without changing the current code too much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi please try this one

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("http://www-proxy.us.abc.com:80");
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
```

I hope it will work for you.
Thanks

Comment: It would nice if the code read HTTPS_PROXY from an environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer Selenium documentation - https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/http_proxies/

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use JVM flags. That way you don't have to change your code at all.

`java -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://www-proxy.us.abc.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=”localhost|127.0.0.1|10.*.*.*”`